# Display primary key in the SQlite database when selecting item in Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

I am trying to display the primary key of the item I selected in Spinner.I want to display the primary key in TextView.How will I do this?I already know how to display a field in a table in database.

In my DatabseHandler.java
This is how I insert data in my table criteria

```
public long insertLabelCriteria(String label, String label2, String label3){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CRI_NAME, label);
    values.put(KEY_CRI_PER, label2); 
    values.put(KEY_CRI_EVPK, label3);
    // Inserting Row

    long id = db.insert(TABLE_CRITERIA, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    return id;



}
```

This is my method in getting labels and returning list of labels

```
public List<Criteria> getAllLabels( String evpk ){
    List<Criteria> labels = new ArrayList<Criteria>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

   String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CRITERIA + " WHERE "
         + KEY_CRI_EVPK + " = " + evpk ;



    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(new Criteria(cursor.getString(1)));


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
```

}

In my MainActivity

I have a method loadSpinnerData and I use this evrytime I add a criteria, it will load the Spinner to view the item I added in database

```
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<Criteria> lables = db.getAllLabels(evpk.getText().toString());

    // Creating adapter for spinner

    ArrayAdapter<Criteria> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Criteria> (this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    criteria_spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    criteria_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Now, on selecting item, how can I display the primary key of the selected item in spinner?
This codes below are just to show and select the item click.

```
  @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

I also try to add this code ,but the id display is arraylist number, not the primary key

```
 long rowId = id;
 String criteriapk = String.valueOf(label);
 cripk.setText(criteriapk);
```

I find it hard, in finding solution with this.What will I do?Help me plss

I also try this method, but the value is cursor.in the TextView, it does not display number.

```
public Cursor find_id_of_criteria(String label){


SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase(); 
String selectQuery = "SELECT criteria_id FROM Criteria WHERE criteria_name = "+"'" + label +"'";
Cursor id = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


db.close(); 
return  id;
```

}

and in loadSpinnerdata I put this

```
//display id of criteria
        Cursor id2 =      db.find_id_of_criteria(label);
        String cri =(String.valueOf(id2).toString());
        cripk.setText(cri);
```

Comment: The naive way is to query the DB with selected item's value (assuming it's unique and always returns 1 item) and get the primary key. The best way is to implement your custom adapter, as answered by AlexS.

Comment: i added new codes above, i hope you can help me. Is their anyway to convert cursor to long?or string?

Comment: If you do this way, then put your snippet `//display id of criteria` inside `onItemSelected()`. Then use `long id = id2.getLong(0);` to get the id. Be careful to `setText()` with number, as it will refer to String resource instead.

Comment: i tried it and  it says 
the method in setText in TextView is not applicable for argument long.
what will I do now?help me

Comment: Convert it to `String`. You can do it like `cripk.setText(id+"");` or `cripk.setText(String.valueOf(id));`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an own adapter extending BaseAdapter or CursorAdapter class and use it instead of ArrayAdapter.

Here is an example using CursorAdapter. I haven't tested it as it is meant to be a start for your own implementation. Of course you can use other layouts as well, with some minor changes to this code.

```
public class CriteriaCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private class Holder {
        TextView text;
    }

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CriteriaCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }
        Holder holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        Cursor c = (Cursor)getItem(position);
        holder.text.setText(c.getString(1));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Important: If you use CursorAdapter your cursor has to have a column named '_id'. You can achieve this by modifying your SELECT-statement, if your TABLE doesn't contain this column!**

```
SELECT columnPK _id, col1, .... FROM ...
```

To get the primary-key (column '_id' of cursor) you can use `long getItemId(int position);` of your CriteriaCursorAdapter.

You will find many examples for extending BaseAdapter or CursorAdapter. [One Example](http://jimmanz.blogspot.de/2012/06/example-for-listview-using-baseadapter.html?m=1)

Comment: will you please help me?I am new to this one

Comment: I'll post more detailed information later, since writing code on smartphone is not funny.

Comment: i add new codes above, isit helpful?my problem now is that, it does not display the primary key, i think it is the primary key equivalent to cursor.is their anyway to make it long or string?

Answer (score 0):

Simple.. You are almost near to answer. Change your `getAllLabels` as following way.

```
public List<Criteria> getAllLabels( String evpk ){
List<Criteria> labels = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CRITERIA + " WHERE "
     + KEY_CRI_EVPK + " = " + evpk ;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        Criteria ct = new Criteria();
        ct.setLabel(cursor.getString(1));
        ct.setKey(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
        labels.add(ct);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// closing connection
cursor.close();
db.close();

// returning lables
return labels;
}
```

Here I changed the do while loop only. In this way create getters and setters for label and key. To get the primary key use the selected Criteria object like `ct.getKey`; I hope this will help you.

**UPDATE**

```
List<String> field_key; //accessible in whole class.
private void loadSpinnerData() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// database handler
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

// Spinner Drop down elements
List<Criteria> lables = db.getAllLabels(evpk.getText().toString());
List<String> field_lables = new ArrayList<String>();
field_key = new ArrayList<String>();

// Creating adapter for spinner
for (Criteria ct : lables) {
    field_lables.add(ct.getLabel);
    field_key.add(ct.getkey);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, field_lables);

// Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
dataAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// attaching data adapter to spinner
criteria_spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
criteria_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

&

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String key = field_key.get(position).toString();


    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label+" Your key: " + key,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Try this way and let me know what happens

Comment: where do I put ct.getKey?What should I put in OnItemSelected?Help me plss